# How to sort response in Ready API using groovy in ascending and descending order

Tags: groovy, automation, ready-api

I have gone through various articles but didn't find any simple way to sort the API response in ascending or descending order using groovy. Can someone please help on this?

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def inputJson = '''{
   "status" : "success",
   "locale" : "",
   "data" : {
      "periods" : [
         {
            "payCycleId" : "custompayperiod",
            "sequence" : 1,
            "cycleStartDate" : "2018-10-01",
            "cycleEndDate" : "2018-10-08"
         },
         {
            "payCycleId" : "custompayperiod",
            "sequence" : 2,
            "cycleStartDate" : "2018-10-09",
            "cycleEndDate" : "2018-10-16"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Want to sort above response based on sequence.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways.
For example:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputJson)
//Descending
json.data.periods = json.data.periods.toSorted { a, b -> b.sequence <=> a.sequence }
//Ascending
//json.data.periods = json.data.periods.toSorted { a, b -> a.sequence <=> b.sequence }
String output = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(json))
```